# Disable application loading/routing in Angular2

Tags: angular, configuration, angular2-router

I have an angular2 application (RC6 version), where some important global parameters are loaded from a configuration file using a service that collects this file on startup:

```
@NgModule({
imports:  [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, AppRoutes, SomeCustomModule ],
declarations: [ AppComponent ]
providers: [
            ConfigurationService,
            {
              provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
              useFactory: (config: ConfigurationService) => () => { 
                             return config.load().then(configParams=> { return true;});      
                          },
              deps: [ConfigurationService, HttpModule],
              multi: true
            }
          ],
bootstrap:[ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

As shown in this snippet i use what i call a **ConfigurationService** which through an http call reads a configuration file and returns some parameters (as a Promise). If everything goes well, the application loads perfectly and these config parameters are accessible throughout the sub-modules etc.

The question is, how can i stop application from loading the sub-modules in case this configuration file does not load as expected? (Please note that the AppComponent is in essence just a router-outlet, redirecting to other routes, defined by multiple sub-modules). Can i "disable" or redirect to an error page instead of loading the module/component defined by the requested route?

Comment: In AppComponent check parameters. If they are as expected, let the app run else route to error page...

Comment: Yes, but where? The AppComponent template is just `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. I tried to encapsulate it with an *ngIf but i receive an error "Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load ChildComponent"

Do you mean to add an ngOnInit() function and perform the check inside it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To disable initial routing of the page, and let it handle depending on your `ConfigurationService` you have to set [**`initialNavigation`**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ExtraOptions-interface.html#!#initialNavigation-anchor) to `false` in your `AppRoutes` object:

```
export const AppRoutes = RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, {initialNavigation : false});
```

Within your `ConfigurationService` you then have to inject the `router` and use this to navigate depending on your configuration.

Another option is to use the `canActivate` routing hook. Within this hook you can inject the `ConfigurationService` and let it determine whether it could load this page or not.

---

**update**

For the latest version of angular, the `false` value for `initialNavigation` is deprectated, use `'disabled'` instead:

```
{ initialNavigation : 'disabled' }
```

Comment: Thanks, i was not aware of the `{initialNavigation : false}` option

Comment: +1 Just an awesome feature by awesome Angular team, Thanks for letting us know, any documentation/reference link..?

Comment: @PankajParkar I've added a link to the api. I don't think it's in the documentation yet

Comment: @PierreDuc Thanks  mate, it would be helpful to other as well :)